# How to compare next looped data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, yfinance

Im trying to get BTC USD data for 1 min in day and then for each open value im comparing the first open value with the next if its greater than the first value then buy and vice versa
This is what Ive got:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers='BTC-USD', period='1d', interval='1m')
Opens = data['Open'].to_numpy()
for x in Opens:
    for y in Opens:
        if x > y:
            print("Buy")
        else: 
            print("Sell")
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Storing all the Buy/Sell into a column named `decision`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers='BTC-USD', period='1d', interval='1m')
Opens = data[['Open']]
Opens['decision'] = np.where(Opens['Open'] > Opens['Open'].shift(1), 'Buy', 'Sell')
print(Opens)
```